# Test code from Akka documentation runs strangely

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-testkit

I am learning test methods in the Akka actor model. I tried to run some code from the Akka documentation. When I run the following code, a confusing error occurs. I'm using JDK 1.8.121, macOS, and Scala 2.12.

The code from the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#replying-to-messages-received-by-probes):

```
val probe = TestProbe()
val future = probe.ref ? "hello"
probe.expectMsg(0 millis, "hello") // TestActor runs on CallingThreadDispatcher
probe.reply("world")
assert(future.isCompleted && future.value == Some(Success("world")))
```

I set up the test on my own computer:

```
package TestKitDemo

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Status.Success
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, WordSpecLike}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Try

class ReplyDemo extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Testsystem")) with WordSpecLike
with BeforeAndAfterAll{
//  import system.dispatcher
  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    shutdown(system)
  }

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
  "reply" should {
    "same" in {

      val probe = TestProbe()
      val future = probe.ref ? "hello"
      probe.expectMsg(0 millis, "hello") // TestActor runs on CallingThreadDispatcher
      probe.reply("world")


      // error
      assert(future.isCompleted && future.value == Some(Success("world")))

      // correct
//      assert(future.isCompleted && future.value.get == Try("world"))

    }
  }
}
```

I use two types of `assert`: one is the code in the [Akka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#replying-to-messages-received-by-probes), the other is my own equality test using `Try`.

I have an idea about what `Try` is. To my knowledge, `Try` is a type that can be `Success` or `Failure`.

The test error is below:

```
future.isCompleted was true, but Some(Success("world")) did not equal Some(Success(world))
ScalaTestFailureLocation: TestKitDemo.ReplyDemo at (ReplyDemo.scala:44)
Expected :Some(Success(world))
Actual   :future.isCompleted was true, but Some(Success("world"))
```

`Some(Success("world"))` is not equal to `Some(Success(world))`. What's wrong? They should be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assert(future.isCompleted && future.value == Some(Success("world")))
```

The reason the above assertion fails in your test is because you're trying to match on `akka.actor.Status.Success` instead of `scala.util.Success`. Replace

```
import akka.actor.Status.Success
```

with

```
import scala.util.Success
```

and your test will pass.